# Microsoft Graph API - how to grant access for my inbox via API to specific user(s)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a question about handling permission grants of inboxes via Microsoft Graph API. 
Is it possible via Microsoft Graph API to grant another user the access permission to my inbox messages?

I dont found any suitable operation until now.

Retrieving relased mailboxes from another user works fine, but how to make my own inbox visible to specific user that he has the grant to access my inbox?

I dont found a operation under:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users.....

or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me.......

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you'll need delegated access.

> - If the app has the appropriate delegated permissions from one user, and another user has shared a mail folder with that user, or, has given delegated access to that user.

At this moment you have no way to share your mailbox by using the api. If you however shared your mailbox with some other user, they will be able to access it.

I think it's a good thing that you cannot share your mailbox from an app, because it would be easy to compromise a mailbox of some user by a malicious app. If you really want you might be able to share the users mailbox by using EWS (that is the same connection the Outlook app uses).